# LoginTask(AsyncTask) NullPointer

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I try to fix this bug but i know why something **nullpointer**, some can return `json` success.

```
public class Login extends Activity {
public TextView loginErrorMsg;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private JSONObject jsonResult;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bus_login);
            //findViewById
}

public void btnLogin_OnClick(View v) {

    new LoginTask().execute();
}

class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String uname = inputUserId.getText().toString();
        String password =inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions vehicleFunction = new UserFunctions();
        jsonResult = vehicleFunction.loginVehicle(uname, password);

        return jsonResult;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonResult) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        try {

            int success = jsonResult.getInt("success");
            if (success == 1) {
                loginErrorMsg.setText("success");

            } else{
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Fail");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

}

```
public JSONObject loginVehicle(String vehicleId, String password){
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vehicleId", vehicleId));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginVehicleURL, params);
    return json;
}


01-27 23:44:12.438: W/System.err(2121): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 23:44:12.438: W/System.err(2121):     at com.ptms.Bus_Login$LoginTask.onPostExecute(Bus_Login.java:79)
01-27 23:44:12.448: W/System.err(2121):     at com.ptms.Bus_Login$LoginTask.onPostExecute(Bus_Login.java:1)
01-27 23:44:12.448: W/System.err(2121):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-27 23:44:12.458: W/System.err(2121):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you please indicate the line no 79 of Bus_Login.java class.

Comment: Bus_Login.java=Login.java

Comment: I am asking what is written on line no 79.

Comment: int success = jsonResult.getInt("success");

Comment: Your problem is that jsonResult is null. Debug your application and check where you are retrieving json data then you will find your answer..

Comment: double check `loginVehicle()` and see if `return json` ever returns null.

Comment: BUT if i add the code in the btnLogin_OnClick
"
  String uname = inputUserId.getText().toString();
  String password =inputPassword.getText().toString();
  UserFunctions vehicleFunction = new UserFunctions();
  jsonResult = vehicleFunction.loginVehicle(uname, password);
"
and add
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
into OnCreate, i can get the json successful.

Comment: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-BSHvYT9kddQ/UQVT-1pXsCI/AAAAAAAAB-k/V-couGmG6rs/s1198/2.JPG
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yRjP04toN24/UQVT-4nfr0I/AAAAAAAAB-o/vkSYxO2EE5o/s1226/1.JPG

Comment: @user1992802 I have explained your answer below. check it.

Comment: What's your `jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl`? It use asycntask again?  or used a new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **debug** you application in eclipse.

Check in this method. I guess it return null in json.

```
public JSONObject loginVehicle(String vehicleId, String password){
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vehicleId", vehicleId));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginVehicleURL, params);
    return json;
}
```

**Check in this line**

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginVehicleURL, params);
```

and you are accessing jsonResult which contain null.

```
int success = jsonResult.getInt("success");
```

Comment: BUT if i add the code in the btnLogin_OnClick 'String uname = inputUserId.getText().toString(); String password =inputPassword.getText().toString(); UserFunctions vehicleFunction = new UserFunctions(); jsonResult = vehicleFunction.loginVehicle(uname, password); ' 
and add 'StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);' into OnCreate, i can get the json successful.

Comment: if i want to test can i get the json return, i need to enable the strict mode because of android>=3.0. 
and i get the result is yes. i can get the return json, not null

i need to complete asynctask, because i need run this app>=android3.

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-BSHvYT9kddQ/UQVT-1pXsCI/AAAAAAAAB-k/V-couGmG6rs/s1198/2.JPG
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yRjP04toN24/UQVT-4nfr0I/AAAAAAAAB-o/vkSYxO2EE5o/s1226/1.JPG

Comment: if i enable strict mode and do it in asyncTask, still return nullpointer. if i put it into btnLogin_onclick, i get can the return json.
anyway thx again

Comment: Its because i think you are running application android>=3.0. If you do network operation on main thread android>=3.0 which is now allow so its giving null in json. Here now you using the strict mode then its allows to do network operation and getting correct json. Another way to get json in async class then there is no need to write 'StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);'. Its always better to do network operation in asynchronous class.

Comment: the problem is If i get json in async class, it will return null whether i add strict mode or not, but if i pull it into main thread, i get the json.  and i want to solve the problem how to get the json in async class not return null json to me.